# Asking a question that has already been asked but which does not have an answer

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, old-questions

I have a question for which I would like to get an answer, but it was already asked (and left unanswered) several years ago. Since it is unlikely to gain any attention at this point, is it appropriate to repost it? If not, what options are available to me to generate further interest in the previously asked question?

[Flip left-right Plotly Horizontal Histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799469/flip-left-right-plotly-horizontal-histogram)

Comment: I'm no expert in that field, but the question that you link to appears somewhat anemic, in that it doesn't show the asker's own efforts. Rather than re-ask, improve on it, including showing the results of your own research as well as your own code attempts, explaining how your attempts are not working. Making it as easy as possible to answer your question will go a long way towards having it well accepted and well answered.

Comment: Fair enough. Would it be better to edit that question, or repost it with more effort?

Comment: Could your own question be made at least somewhat different, or would it actually and factually ask for the very same thing? If you're unlucky, asking again might have it closed as a duplicate. Best scenario is that you get a good answer and the older ("anemic" is a good description) can be closed as a dup of *yours*.

Comment: @usr2564301 my question is exactly what is asked in that one. I could certainly ask it better, with more information and some examples to work with, but the core of the question would be literally identical.

Comment: Here is an idea, then, to counteract wannabee-closers. It might be possible to refer to the older question (as in "I am aware of it") but explicitly point out your own attempts and research. Granted, I'm still not sure how that would be received.

Comment: Yea, that might be the simplest way to go about it

Comment: I'd do that, then, if appropriate, I'd vote to close the other one as a duplicate of my more thoroughly-written version.

Comment: ...and in the process of doing research to ask the question better I managed to answer it. So I guess the anemic question gets an answer after all...

Comment: FYI, if a question didn't get any answers, or did but none are up upvoted or marked as the solution, then it isn't eligible as a duplicate candidate. So if you have found a question, but it had no answers, there's not as much wrong with asking it again. Especially if you can sufficiently give more information than the last users so that an answer can be provided.

Comment: ....or you could attach a bonus to the original question and in comment state your bonus stipulations